# Centering Problem (Horizontal)

Tags: javascript, css

I want to center this material horizontally:

```
    <a href='/big.jpg' class = 'cloud-zoom' id='zoom1'
        rel="">
        <img src="/small.jpg" alt='' title="Optional title display" />
    </a>
```

Comment: What do you want to center: the nested image element or entire anchor?

Comment: You *really* need to give us more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to your anchor. I assume your `zoom1` has `display:block` style and its `width` is larger than image's width.

```
<a href='/big.jpg' class = 'cloud-zoom' id='zoom1' rel="" style="display:block; width:400px; border:1px solid red; text-align:center">
    <img src="/small.jpg" alt='' title="Optional title display" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

altough the question is not clear on what needs to be center aligned, here is the link you can check out -

http://www.gtalbot.org/NvuSection/NvuWebDesignTips/HorizontalAlignment.html